# geom_smooth and geom_point do not have legends

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to create a plot that looks like this:
[image]

```
x=1:20
y=sample(20)

df <- tibble(x=x,y=y)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_smooth()+
  geom_point()
```

But the codes unabled to show legends.
Could anyone help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm perhaps being a bit over-literal in your requirements, but you could do:

```r
tibble(x = 1:20, y = sample(20)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "line")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "point"), color = "red", size = 3) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.75, 0.9),
        legend.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(shape = NULL, linetype = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could set them inside their `aes()` as variables:

```
x <- 1:20
y <- sample(20)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(x=x,y=y)

ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+
  geom_smooth(aes(color = "line"))+
  geom_point(aes(color = "point"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue","red"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `ggnewscale` you could try:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)


x=1:20
y=sample(20)

df1 <- tibble(x=x, y=y)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y))+
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = "line"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = "black") +
  labs(colour = NULL)+
  new_scale_colour()+
  geom_point(aes(colour = "point"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = "red")+
  labs(colour = NULL)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>